# Using field value in a pattern for a regular expression match to another field in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm trying to modify an ILIKE match to a ~* match in PostgreSQL and I'm hitting a wall. The objective is matching a field to another field using the second one as a substring of the first one. This is the original query:

```
select a.col1,b.col2 from a,b where a.col1 ilike ('%' || b.col2 || '%')
```

Which is fine but I need to add something like a space or beginning of string clause to avoid too many matches. But, when I try:

```
select a.col1,b.col2 from a,b where a.col1 ~* ('^| ' || b.col2 || '$| ')
```

I get the error 'invalid regular expression: parentheses () not balanced'. I assume I'm either doing something wrong in the query, or that there are characters in the b field that need escaping. I don't think it's really practical to start cleaning that field up if indeed that's the issue.

Is there a way to specify that the field should be read literally, similar to the 'r' prefix for strings in Python? Or am I overlooking another issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no function in PostgreSQL designed to work like `r` in Python. You have to escape parentheses in the text from the second column if you want to use it as a regex, otherwise it will be invalid. You can write a function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION escape_parentheses(text) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN regexp_replace($1, '([()])', '\\\1', 'g');
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and then your query becomes

```
select a.col1,b.col2 from a,b where a.col1 ~* (' ' || escape_parentheses(b.col2) || ' ')
```

I don't know why you added `|` in your regex, it acts as alternation so it will match everything as `^` does. I tested it on the following tables

| `a.col1` | `b.col2` |
| --- | --- |
| This is a test string. | test |
| Another example string. | example |
| Some random text to check. | random |
| No matches here. | nomatch |
|  | (par |
|  | par) |
|  | (par) |

**Result**

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| This is a test string. | test |
| Another example string. | example |
| Some random text to check. | random |

---

P.S. `quote_literal` doesn't work and `E` can be only used on string literals